# Is this a cryptographically secure method to generate a random number in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, random, cryptography

Here's my attempt to replace `Math.random()` with my own `Cryptography.random()`. Will my code generate a cryptographically secure random number and do you see any opportunities for optimization?

```
NodeCrypto = require('crypto');

Cryptography = function() {
}

Cryptography.random = Promise.method(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        NodeCrypto.randomBytes(4, function(ex, buffer) {
            var hex = buffer.toString('hex');
            var integer = parseInt(hex, 16);
            var random = Number('0.'+integer);

            resolve(random);
            return random;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with node.js, but *"with my own Cryptography.random()"* is a red flag, [here is why](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### So what you are trying to achieve is generating a random float between 0 and 1 out of 4 bytes that have been securely generated by a *proper crypto library*?

The way you do it in your question will generate a bias as your `integer` is uniformly distributed amongst the set {0,1,…,4294967295}. For example the union of the ranges

```
{10000000000,…,19999999999},
{1000000000,…,1999999999}
{100000000,…,199999999}
{10000000,…,19999999}
{1000000,…,1999999} 
…
{10,…,19}
{1}
```

that generates a leading 1 as the first decimal digit is about ten times larger than the range that generates a leading 9:

```
{9000000000,…,9999999999}
{900000000,…,999999999}
{90000000,…,99999999}
{9000000,…,9999999} 
…
{90,…,99}
{9}
```

(There are no eleven digit numbers among the possible values of `integer` that have a leading 9.)

Instead you can divide `integer` by its largest possible value which would be `0xffffffff`. As javascript uses 8 byte floating point values for its number types 4 byte values don't give you enough range, though. To be on the safe side you can instead read 8 bytes (which is a little bit more than necessary because of the bits used to store the exponent):

```
//…
NodeCrypto.randomBytes(8, function(ex, buffer) {
    var hex = buffer.toString('hex');
    var integer = parseInt(hex, 16);
    var random = integer / 0xffffffffffffffff;

    resolve(random);
    return random;
});
//…
```

The above generates numbers in the interval [0.0,1.0] (both 0.0 and 1.0 are included in the range). <strike>If you want to exclude the 1.0 you can add 1 to the divisor: `var random = integer / (0xffffffffffffffff+1);`</strike> **Edit**: As the number does not have 8 byte precision in the mantissa it will get rounded to `1.0` regardless of being less than `1.0` mathematically.

[This page](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference) speculates that numbers will be represented by 16byte floating point in future revisions of the ECMA standard. If you want to prepare for that you can use 16 instead of 8 bytes randomness and divide by `0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`

I'll conclude with a few words of warning: For cryptographic applications the random number you generate via this message are likely to be completely insecure as with less than 64bit of randomness you have by far to few entropy. And generally oleksii is right with his comment: Don't invent or even implement your own crypto.

Comment: I was first - slightly shorter answer though :)

Comment: @owlstead, both by a small margin only ;)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Hi Perseids, is it possible to generate 64bit of randomness by altering my function above? Would I just need to tweak a few of the values?

Comment: @Kirk: I don't get what you are asking. The tweak I proposed in my answer generates 64bit random floats already. What functionality are you missing?

Comment: @Perseids ah my bad, so if I use 8 random bytes and do the division (integer / 0xffffffffffffffff), I have enough entropy in my random number to be considered cryptographically secure?

Comment: No, but the problem is that 64 bit randomness is not enough. You need at least 80 bit, but 128 bit is a comfortable value. Note, though, that floats do not have enough precision to hold that much randomness. Besides, what do you want to use the floats for? I've only ever seen floats used in rather obscure cryptographic algorithms. (@Kirk)

Comment: @Perseids: Doesn't the distribution get skewed by the loss of precision in the `var integer = parseInt(hex, 16);` line? You're parsing a hex string with *way* more significant digits than the longest reliable int in a IEEE-754 binary64 value. Are we sure that the 52 (real) bits of mantissa we get from that really are as random as the input hex? (Mind you, as you said, with only 53 (effective) bits of mantissa, we're already in really weak territory from a crypto perspective.)

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect, the first digits of `integer` are certainly biased. That's not a good method to create a decimal value from 0 to 1 (exclusive).